# Decision Tree Classifier I keep getting NaN error

Tags: python, numpy, machine-learning, scikit-learn, decision-tree

I've a small decision tree code and I believe I convert everything to int, and I have checked my train/test data with isnan, max etc.

I genuinely have no idea why its giving that error.

So I'm trying to pass Mnist dataset from Decision Tree and then I'll attack using a class.

Here is the code:

```
 from AttackUtils import Attack
    from AttackUtils import calc_output_weighted_weights, targeted_gradient, non_targeted_gradient, non_targeted_sign_gradient
    (X_train_woae, y_train_woae), (X_test_woae, y_test_woae) = mnist.load_data()
    X_train_woae = X_train_woae.reshape((len(X_train_woae), np.prod(X_train_woae.shape[1:])))
    X_test_woae = X_test_woae.reshape((len(X_test_woae), np.prod(X_test_woae.shape[1:])))

    from sklearn import tree
    #model_woae = LogisticRegression(multi_class='multinomial', solver='lbfgs', fit_intercept=False)
    model_woae = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(class_weight='balanced')
    model_woae.fit(X_train_woae, y_train_woae)
    #model_woae.coef_ = model_woae.feature_importances_
    coef_int = np.round(model_woae.tree_.compute_feature_importances(normalize=False) * X_train_woae.size).astype(int)
    attack_woae = Attack(model_woae)
    attack_woae.prepare(X_train_woae, y_train_woae, X_test_woae, y_test_woae)
    weights_woae = attack_woae.weights
    num_classes_woae = len(np.unique(y_train_woae))
    attack_woae.create_one_hot_targets(y_test_woae)
    attack_woae.attack_to_max_epsilon(non_targeted_gradient, 50)
    non_targeted_scores_woae = attack_woae.scores
```

So the attack class does perturbation and non-targeted gradient attack. **And here is the attack class:**

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score


def calc_output_weighted_weights(output, w):
    for c in range(len(output)):
        if c == 0:
            weighted_weights = output[c] * w[c]
        else:
            weighted_weights += output[c] * w[c]
    return weighted_weights


def targeted_gradient(foolingtarget, output, w):
    ww = calc_output_weighted_weights(output, w)
    for k in range(len(output)):
        if k == 0:
            gradient = foolingtarget[k] * (w[k]-ww)
        else:
            gradient += foolingtarget[k] * (w[k]-ww)
    return gradient


def non_targeted_gradient(target, output, w):
    ww = calc_output_weighted_weights(output, w)
    for k in range(len(target)):
        if k == 0:
            gradient = (1-target[k]) * (w[k]-ww)
        else:
            gradient += (1-target[k]) * (w[k]-ww)
    return gradient


def non_targeted_sign_gradient(target, output, w):
    gradient = non_targeted_gradient(target, output, w)
    return np.sign(gradient)


class Attack:

    def __init__(self, model):
        self.fooling_targets = None
        self.model = model

    def prepare(self, X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test):
        self.images = X_test
        self.true_targets = y_test
        self.num_samples = X_test.shape[0]
        self.train(X_train, y_train)
        print("Model training finished.")
        self.test(X_test, y_test)
        print("Model testing finished. Initial accuracy score: " + str(self.initial_score))

    def set_fooling_targets(self, fooling_targets):
        self.fooling_targets = fooling_targets

    def train(self, X_train, y_train):
        self.model.fit(X_train, y_train)
        self.weights = self.model.coef_
        self.num_classes = self.weights.shape[0]

    def test(self, X_test, y_test):
        self.preds = self.model.predict(X_test)
        self.preds_proba = self.model.predict_proba(X_test)
        self.initial_score = accuracy_score(y_test, self.preds)

    def create_one_hot_targets(self, targets):
        self.one_hot_targets = np.zeros(self.preds_proba.shape)
        for n in range(targets.shape[0]):
            self.one_hot_targets[n, targets[n]] = 1

    def attack(self, attackmethod, epsilon):
        perturbed_images, highest_epsilon = self.perturb_images(epsilon, attackmethod)
        perturbed_preds = self.model.predict(perturbed_images)
        score = accuracy_score(self.true_targets, perturbed_preds)
        return perturbed_images, perturbed_preds, score, highest_epsilon

    def perturb_images(self, epsilon, gradient_method):
        perturbed = np.zeros(self.images.shape)
        max_perturbations = []
        for n in range(self.images.shape[0]):
            perturbation = self.get_perturbation(epsilon, gradient_method, self.one_hot_targets[n], self.preds_proba[n])
            perturbed[n] = self.images[n] + perturbation
            max_perturbations.append(np.max(perturbation))
        highest_epsilon = np.max(np.array(max_perturbations))
        return perturbed, highest_epsilon

    def get_perturbation(self, epsilon, gradient_method, target, pred_proba):
        gradient = gradient_method(target, pred_proba, self.weights)
        inf_norm = np.max(gradient)
        perturbation = epsilon / inf_norm * gradient
        return perturbation

    def attack_to_max_epsilon(self, attackmethod, max_epsilon):
        self.max_epsilon = max_epsilon
        self.scores = []
        self.epsilons = []
        self.perturbed_images_per_epsilon = []
        self.perturbed_outputs_per_epsilon = []
        for epsilon in range(0, self.max_epsilon):
            perturbed_images, perturbed_preds, score, highest_epsilon = self.attack(attackmethod, epsilon)
            self.epsilons.append(highest_epsilon)
            self.scores.append(score)
            self.perturbed_images_per_epsilon.append(perturbed_images)
            self.perturbed_outputs_per_epsilon.append(perturbed_preds)
```

And this is the traceback it gives:

ValueError

> Traceback (most recent call last)  in
>   
>         4 num_classes_woae = len(np.unique(y_train_woae))
>         5 attack_woae.create_one_hot_targets(y_test_woae)
>   ----> 6 attack_woae.attack_to_max_epsilon(non_targeted_gradient, 50)
>         7 non_targeted_scores_woae = attack_woae.scores
>
> ~\MULTIATTACK\AttackUtils.py in
>   attack_to_max_epsilon(self, attackmethod, max_epsilon)
>       106         self.perturbed_outputs_per_epsilon = []
>       107         for epsilon in range(0, self.max_epsilon):
>   --> 108             perturbed_images, perturbed_preds, score, highest_epsilon = self.attack(attackmethod, epsilon)
>       109             self.epsilons.append(highest_epsilon)
>       110             self.scores.append(score)
>
> ~\MULTIATTACK\AttackUtils.py in attack(self,
>   attackmethod, epsilon)
>        79     def attack(self, attackmethod, epsilon):
>        80         perturbed_images, highest_epsilon = self.perturb_images(epsilon, attackmethod)
>   ---> 81         perturbed_preds = self.model.predict(perturbed_images)
>        82         score = accuracy_score(self.true_targets, perturbed_preds)
>        83         return perturbed_images, perturbed_preds, score, highest_epsilon
>
> ...\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py
>   in predict(self, X, check_input)
>       413         """
>       414         check_is_fitted(self, 'tree_')
>   --> 415         X = self._validate_X_predict(X, check_input)
>       416         proba = self.tree_.predict(X)
>       417         n_samples = X.shape[0]
>
> ...\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\tree\tree.py
>   in _validate_X_predict(self, X, check_input)
>       374         """Validate X whenever one tries to predict, apply, predict_proba"""
>       375         if check_input:
>   --> 376             X = check_array(X, dtype=DTYPE, accept_sparse="csr")
>       377             if issparse(X) and (X.indices.dtype != np.intc or
>       378                                 X.indptr.dtype != np.intc):
>
> ...\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py
>   in check_array(array, accept_sparse, accept_large_sparse, dtype,
>   order, copy, force_all_finite, ensure_2d, allow_nd,
>   ensure_min_samples, ensure_min_features, warn_on_dtype, estimator)
>       566         if force_all_finite:
>       567             _assert_all_finite(array,
>   --> 568                                allow_nan=force_all_finite == 'allow-nan')
>       569 
>       570     shape_repr = _shape_repr(array.shape)
>
> ...\appdata\local\programs\python\python35\lib\site-packages\sklearn\utils\validation.py
>   in _assert_all_finite(X, allow_nan)
>        54                 not allow_nan and not np.isfinite(X).all()):
>        55             type_err = 'infinity' if allow_nan else 'NaN, infinity'
>   ---> 56             raise ValueError(msg_err.format(type_err, X.dtype))
>        57 
>        58
>
> ValueError: Input contains NaN, infinity or a value too large for
>   dtype('float32').

**EDIT:**

I've added coefficient numbers as 0 and it now gives the same error just below the line, at `attack.attack_to_max_epsilon(non_targeted_gradient, epsilon_number)`

Comment: maybe just float32 overflow, but lol the digit is huge

Comment: @user8426627 I've made them smaller but still the same... You were talking about coef_int digits right?

Comment: try to apply one-hot encode to your targets or labels before to train the clf,.

Comment: @FreddyDaniel can you give more detail? I'm not sure I completely understood

Comment: I think that you are new in machine learning, please see what is one-hot enconde https://machinelearningmastery.com/why-one-hot-encode-data-in-machine-learning/ and then try to search dataset normalization to train machine learning algorithms.

Comment: @FreddyDaniel can you show with to code? I'll accept it as an answer

Answer (score 0):

Try to apply one-hot enconde to your labels before to train..

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

mylabels= ["label1", "label2", "label2"..."n.label"]
le = LabelEncoder()
labels = le.fit_transform(mylabels)
```

and then try to split your data:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
(x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test) = train_test_split(data,
                                                     labels,
                                                     test_size=0.25)
```

now probably your labels will be encoded with numbers which is good to train a machine learning algorithm.

Comment: The thing is algorithm works fine with others and I'm using Mnist so afaik labels come with it. The problem is with decision tree classifier. I've made an edit to question